# Flutter animation stops on user click, but navigation doesn't occur. How can I make cards clickable during animation to trigger navigation?

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-animation

I'm encountering an issue in Flutter where the user clicks during an animation it will halt the animation but fail to trigger navigation. Specifically, I have cards with animation effects (sliding right to left), and I want them to be clickable on the first interaction, even during the animation.

How can I achieve this? I've tried pausing the animation upon user click, but navigation doesn't occur. Any insights or alternative approaches to address this would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "Specifically, I have cards with animation effects," - what effects?

Comment: Sliding left to right effects @pskink